# vsftpd error: 530 Login incorrect (and various others when trying other solutions on this website)

Tags: ssl, vsftpd, arch-linux

I know this question has been asked countless times already, but I feel like I've tried every possible solution and none seem to work.

Some articles I've read and tried to use:

[vsftpd error 530 login incorrect occurs with valid credentials](https://serverfault.com/questions/924478/vsftpd-error-530-login-incorrect-error-occurs-with-valid-credentials) and the 5 articles that one links to.
[AskUbuntu - vsftpd 530 login incorrect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413677/vsftpd-530-login-incorrect) and about 10 that offer the same solution.
[LinuxQuestions.org - vsftpd login incorrect](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/vsftpd-login-incorrect-4175417566/)

I used to have UFW enabled (with 20:22/tcp and 20000:20200/tcp allowed) for both active and passive FTP, but have at some point disabled the entire thing.

I tried using xinetd, but got it working just as well as vsftpd-standalone, with exception of errors '500 OOPS: run two copies of vsftpd for IPv4 and IPv6' and '500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket'. However, after solving those two, the same problem (Error 530) occured.

My normal configuration file (/etc/vsftpd.conf) looks like this:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to the 'server name' FTP server.
deny_email_enable=YES
banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/etc/vsftpdjail
listen=YES
#listen_ipv6=YES
ssl_enable=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=NO
#ssl_tlsv1=YES
#ssl_sslv2=NO
#ssl_sslv3=NO
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
require_ssl_reuse=NO
pasv_min_port=20000
pasv_max_port=20200
pasv_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

However, commenting everything from `deny_email_enable` and downward (disabling passive, ssl and pam), with exception of 'listen=YES' doesn't yield other results.

vsftpd.service is enabled and started in systemctl

xinetd.service is disabled and stopped in systemctl (after some testing)

The PAM file (/etc/pam.d/vsftpd) contains:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed
#@include common-account
#@include common-session
#@include common-auth
auth    required    pam_shells.so
```

The files referred to DO exist and have the permissions: root:root 744

My user name is NOT in /etc/ftpusers

My user's login shell (/bin/bash) IS in /etc/shells

My user IS in /etc/passwd

Whenever I try to login I just get the same error over and over again:

```
Connecting to 192.168.178.49:21...
Connection made, awaiting welcome message...
Initializing TLS...
Checking certificate...
Established TLS-connection.
USER username
331 Please specify the password.
PASS ************
530 Login incorrect.
Fatal error: Can't connect to server.
```

'sudo netstat -tulpn' shows:
`tcp     0   0   0.0.0.0:21      0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      342/vsftpd`

/var/log/vsftpd.log shows the same message over and over again:

```
CONNECT: Client "192.168.178.69"
[username] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.178.69"
```

without any further info. (Using the same login credentials as I use to login through SSH and locally on the server)

I am completely out of ideas, after having researched this issue for 6 continuous hours. So any help is appreaciated.

Also, system info: 
`Processor: 2xIntel Pentium G6950@2.800GHz (intel-ucode IS installed)
OS: Arch Linux 5.0.9-arch1-1-ARCH x86_64 (Up-to-date and installed today)
RAM: 8192MB
Internet both Server and Client: 1Gbps cat 5e cable directly to modem
No firewall on client or modem`

Edit1: Edited typos in /etc/pam.d/vsftpd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted the question, I tried a for a little longer, but to no avail. Fast-forward one day and I've decided to completely wipe the operating system, reinstall and make vsftpd the very, very first thing to do after OS essentials. Therefore, I am not sure if what I changed fixed the issue, or if something went wrong during the initial installation of the operating system, but here we go anyway:

I was completely baffled why NO solutions from others, who had the same issue, helped, until I read [the last entry in the Arch Linux vsftpd troubleshooting page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon#vsftpd:_failure_to_log_in_with_correct_password_(because_of_PAM)) which states, that PAM has been updated in 2019(!) and that authentication for **local** users now works differently. Provided is also, an example /etc/pam.d/vsftpd file:

```
#%PAM-1.0
account    required    pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=user sense=allow file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
account    required    pam_unix.so
auth       required    pam_unix.so
```

And all of a sudden, it works.

I only added one line to the config file, when I was testing things and had enabled the 'anonymous' user, and got a 'directory listing' error. This was also adviced in the troubleshooting section of the same page.

```
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

But I honestly doubt that changed anything for logging in for local users, which was my initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the myriad of answers - I had a non-standard shell assigned to the users accounts and it needed to be added to /etc/shells.

Comment: My vsftpd account has /sbin/nologin as shell, so add "/sbin/nologin" into /etc/shells make the 530 error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Wisegay, I think this might be user directory permission issue could you please check url https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd for user dir permission and pam file contents. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't been using vsftpd for a while and forgotten that nice `530: login incorrect` thing.

Spent couple of hours playing around with all the possible solutions I managed to google, and finally recalled the root cause of the issue:

While `pam_service_name=ftp` is documented as a default value, default minimal config didn't work (RHEL7.5, vsftpd3.0.2) throwing `login incorrect` error.

The error was gone when `pam_service_name=vsftpd` was set in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`